# Using Selenium IDE to verify link title attribute

Tags: javascript, html, testing, selenium-ide

I am relatively new to Selenium testing and I have seen the other posts about getting attributes from links. None of the posted solutions I have tried seem to work for my situation. I have the following:

```
<a href="javascript: editFolder(0);" class="htmlLinkImageNoUnderline" title="Edit File">
    <img src="/images/myWorkspace/edit_30x30.png" class="htmlImageNoBorder">
</a>
<a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="htmlLinkImageNoUnderline" title="Download File">
  <img src="/images/myWorkspace/download_file_30x30.png" class="htmlImageNoBorder">
</a>
```

What I am attempting to do with Selenium IDE is verify the existence of these links with their respective titles (Edit File, Download File).  Xpath won't work as these appear in a dynamic table.

Comment: What language:  Java/C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure about your XPath syntax? You should use syntax like this :

```
//a[@title='Download File']
```

Comment: That was it! Thank you very much. Am now able to use the following:  

Command: verifyElementPresent  
Target: //a[@title='Download File']

Answer (score 1):

use firepath to find xpath of a element. see in the image how to find xpath

[image]

Answer (score -2):

I am not sure this XPath is correct or not. I copied it from Firebug:

```
/html/body/form/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/nav/div[1]/ul/li[2]/a/span
```